# Accessing JavaScript Properties in Custom ASP.NET AJAX Server Control

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am creating a custom ASP.NET AJAX server control in which multiple instances of the control may be placed on the page.  That control wraps JavaScript objects, which I need access to those objects for each individual control.  For example, the JavaScript object may have a property called "x" and control1 might have x set to 5 and control2 might x set to 10.  How do I get access to each individual control's JavaScript objects?  Here is a bit of a code snippet that might help:

**HTML**

```
    <CustomControl:MyControl ID="MyControl1" runat="server" x="5"/>
    <CustomControl:MyControl ID="MyControl2" runat="server" x="10"/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
alert(MyControl1.x); //result 5
alert(MyControl2.x); //result 10
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'get access to each individual control's JavaScript objects'? Do you want a single script to know about each wrapped object, for example?

Comment: I am interested in accessing the JavaScript properties for each control.  MyControl1 will have different values for individual properties than MyControl2, and I need to gain access to each controls local properties rather than place it in some global scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris's suggested articles led me to the right solution.  In order to get access to the JavaScript properties of a custom control, you must use the ScriptControl's library to execute the $find function to locate your control.  For example:

**JavaScript in ASP.NET page implementing control**

```
var ctrl1 = $find("<%=MyControl1.ClientID%>");
var ctrl2 = $find("<%=MyControl2.ClientID%>");

ctrl.set_x(5);
alert(ctrl1.x); //result 5

ctrl2.set_x(10);
alert(ctrl2.x); //result 10
```

**JavaScript in Control**

```
CustomControl.MyControl = function(element) {
   CustomControl.MyControl.initializeBase (this, [element]);

   this.x = null;

}

CustomControl.MyControl.prototype = {
    set_x: function(value) {
          this.x = value;     
    } 
}
```

---

Note: I'm not sure of etiquitte for answering your own question.  I will up-vote Chris's answer for helping me get to the right article.  If there are other etiquiite rules I am happy to oblige.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some links that should help you with building custom server controls using ASP.NET AJAX:

Article:

[ASP.NET AJAX: Create AJAX Server Controls using the ScriptControl base class](http://pietschsoft.com/post.aspx?id=e78fc882-c172-46bd-ac8c-3a8d5ea56b14)

[ASP.NET 3.5: Create AJAX Extender Controls using the ExtenderControl base class](http://pietschsoft.com/post.aspx?id=ba924765-2328-4995-a254-6a88d4e4ac11)

Video:

[[How Do I:] Build a Custom ASP.NET AJAX Server Control?](http://www.asp.net/Learn/ajax-videos/video-170.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use the dreaded eval() function to turn the string into JSON,

Here is a great post to help you on your way : [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)